# How to get back my hover after resetting color with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, reset

I have this little jQuery-code working, but there's one thing I can't figure out. After I have clicked my infocontent-menu, the h1:hover is gone. How do I get the hover function back?

HTML:

```
<div class="infocontent"><h1>Wat?</h1></div>
<div class="infocontent"><h1>Van/ voor wie?</h1></div>
<div class="infocontent"><h1>Akties</h1></div>
<div class="infocontent"><h1>Met wie?</h1></div>
```

CSS:

```
.infocontent {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120;
    float: left;
}

.infocontent h1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #999;
}

.infocontent h1:hover { color: #000; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.infocontent h1:first').css('color', '#000');

$(".infocontent h1").on("click", function() {
    $('.infocontent h1').css('color', '#999');
    $(this).css('color', '#000');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FXetb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to change the js to change the class with something like:

```
$('.infocontent h1').eq(0).addClass('on').end().on("click", function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $('.on').removeClass('on'); 
        $(this).addClass('on');
    }
});
```

and change the css to something like this

**EDIT: saw you wanted background changes**

```
.infocontent{float: left}

.infocontent h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #999999;
    /* opt changes */
    font-size: 18px;
    padding:3px 8px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    cursor:pointer/*so users know to click it*/  
}

.infocontent h1.on,.infocontent h1.on:hover{color:#000000;background-color:#CCCCCC}
.infocontent h1:hover {color:#666666;background-color:#EDEDED}
```

I updated your fiddle (now with bg changes): http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/FXetb/18/

Comment: I updated the link to add background color support as well, saw your comment about it. made some optional changes too, seemed to be more fun.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm gonna stick to my original code for the background although your version has less code, 'cause since I started with jQuery yesterday it's gonna cost me some time to adapt your code the way I want the things to change :P
Here's a [link](http://payitforwardarnhem.nl/index4.php) to the site I'm using it for:

Comment: yes, seeing it in context is much better and that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since the jQuery is adding inline CSS, the only way to overwrite this - unfortunately - is via `!important`

**Updated CSS**

```
.infocontent h1:hover {
    color: #000!important;
}
```

[**jsFiddle - it works.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4y4W6/)

I would suggest avoiding the usage of `!important` altogether. You could do this by changing the jQuery to add/remove a CSS class as opposed to adding inline styling.

Comment: Too bad, the background coloring of the infocontent div isn't working when !important is added.
Could I fix this by using [.on("hover" func] or [.hover()], not needing css:hover at all?

Comment: @PascalGerritsen What do you mean it's not working.. it works here http://jsfiddle.net/4y4W6/

Comment: The h1:hover is working ;) But I have a very similar script to change the background color of the h1-parent and that one isn't working anymore when !important is added to h1.

Comment: @PascalGerritsen Wasn't aware of that.. Can you show me an example? I'll fix it

Comment: It's already fixed, but thanks anyway! I'm using it at this [link](http://payitforwardarnhem.nl/index4.php)